# Send Key does not fire until double-click

Tags: vb.net

The combination of Shift+Ctrl+Plus Sign rotates my PDF in a web browser control. However, I have to click the "Rotate" button 2 times before the document rotates. Why?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.WebBrowser1.Focus()
    SendKeys.Send("+(^{+})")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys is an unreliable method for this. I recommend [Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) you can even send multiple keys at once.

Comment: I am still getting the same results with Input Simulator. I have to click the button twice in order for the document to rotate.

Comment: Can you show your code? It may be due to a command hitting when the app cannot take a command that quickly.